# Clojure printing list twice when I only call print once

Tags: clojure

So on a job interview for a Java Dev position, I was asked to design an algorithm to find the ten largest values from an array of 1 million values. I came up with a simple brute force algorithm that more than satisfied my interviewer. I go in tomorrow for the second round interview.

Because I like to challenge myself I have been reading "Clojure for the Brave and True" and got to the section on Lazy Sequences and Collections shortly after the interview and started wondering if I couldn't implement a Clojure function to do the same task.

I got the actual filtering function working correctly but cannot understand what I am seeing when I run the app. Here is my code:

```
(defn random-numbers
  ([] (random-numbers 0))
  ([n] (cons n (lazy-seq (random-numbers (rand 10000))))))

(def big-array (take 1000000 (random-numbers)))

(defn top-ten [[big0 big1 big2 big3 big4 big5 big6 big7 big8 big9 :as acc] x]
  (cond
    (> x big0) [x big1 big2 big3 big4 big5 big6 big7 big8 big9]
    (> x big1) [big0 x big2 big3 big4 big5 big6 big7 big8 big9]
    (> x big2) [big0 big1 x big3 big4 big5 big6 big7 big8 big9]
    (> x big3) [big0 big1 big2 x big4 big5 big6 big7 big8 big9]
    (> x big4) [big0 big1 big2 big3 x big5 big6 big7 big8 big9]
    (> x big5) [big0 big1 big2 big3 big4 x big6 big7 big8 big9]
    (> x big6) [big0 big1 big2 big3 big4 big5 x big7 big8 big9]
    (> x big7) [big0 big1 big2 big3 big4 big5 big6 x big8 big9]
    (> x big8) [big0 big1 big2 big3 big4 big5 big6 big7 x big9]
    (> x big9) [big0 big1 big2 big3 big4 big5 big6 big7 big8 x]
    :else acc))

(defn top-ten-list [coll]
  (reduce top-ten [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] coll))

(defn unlines [coll]
  (clojure.string/join \newline coll))

(defn -main []
  (print (unlines (top-ten-list big-array))))

(-main)
```

And it produces the expected output TWICE:

```
9999.978584142405
9999.966008266641
9999.954608202788
9999.925928099525
9999.779899149064
9999.755392364965
9999.75279348399
9999.640257438374
9999.615213138313
9999.447171545269999.978584142405
9999.966008266641
9999.954608202788
9999.925928099525
9999.779899149064
9999.755392364965
9999.75279348399
9999.640257438374
9999.615213138313
9999.44717154526
```

The output changes slightly depending on whether I use print or println, in that the second set output starts on a new line if I use println.

I am fairly sure that the first output is an artifact of the way I am calling functions and handling their results, but I am not sure where I went wrong!

Comment: how are you executing this script? just copy-n-pasted this script, ran it and i only see a single version of the output, not double. in fact, i used [lein exec](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-exec) to run it like this:  `cat yourscript.clj | lein exec`

Comment: I was running it by clicking the run button/command in IntelliJ....  I will try you method.

Comment: @AlexMiller commented below that dropping the (-main) line would fix the problem in IntelliJ, and it did.  @MatiasElgart's suggestion to use `lien exec` also works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-main` at the bottom is executed when you load the namespace. Then you are invoking `-main` on it, running it again. So, just get rid of the final `(-main)` and you should be done.

Comment: Alex Miller - Thanks for the explanation! That worked.